# Commutant of *-algebra $A\subset B(\mathsf{H})$ is strongly closed

Tags: hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

A quick one.

Suppose that $(f_\lambda)\subset A'$ is strongly convergent to $f\in B(\mathsf{H})$. That is for all $x\in \mathsf{H}$:

$$f_\lambda(x)\to f(x).$$

Let $g\in A$. We want to show that $gf=fg$, as this implies that $f\in A'$. Let $g(x)\in\mathsf{H}$ so that:

$$\lim_\lambda f_\lambda(g(x))=f(g(x)).$$
Also, as $f_\lambda\in A'$, we have:
$$\lim_\lambda f_\lambda(g(x))=\lim_{\lambda}g(f_\lambda(x)).$$

I presume that I am supposed to conclude that this equals $g(f(x))$... but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying a continuous function (the bounded operator $g$) to the convergent net $\{f_\lambda\}$.

Comment: More coffee required (duh!)! Thank you.